# selecting records on a continuous form, sending to a single form- access 2016

Tags: forms, ms-access

I have a continuous form to which I added a checkbox column for each record. I'd like to click on the checkbox and open a single view form for that specific system_id. This is my current code, it's prompting me for an ID field but when I enter the system_id field nothing happens. I don't want a prompt but rather have it seamlessly open the record into the single form. Continuous form is called: [P2P cases] and the single form is called: [P2P View]. Advice please!

current (not working) code:

```
Private Sub View_Click()

Forms("cases").Form.[P2P View].Form.Filter = "qaID=" & Me.system_id.Value
Forms("cases").Form.[P2P View].Form.FilterOn = True
Forms("cases").Form.[P2P View].Visible = True

If Me.system_id.Value = True Then
    Forms("cases").Form.[P2P View].Form.system_id.SetFocus
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You say you want to 'open a single view form', however, your code is structure that addresses a form that is already open and is also setting filter of subform. Can't reference a subform via the main form Form property.  Reference the subform container name. Recommend naming container different from the form it contains, ex.: `Forms("cases").ctrP2P.Form.Filter`

Comment: I have modified the embedded macro on the checkbox (open form = P2P view) to have a where condition reading: [system_id]=[P2P view].[P2P cases].[system_id].

Where:
P2P view = form I want to open 
P2P cases = continuous form 
system_id = unique identifier in which I want to see on the single form.

This is working correctly but it is prompting me to enter a system_id in a pop-up = "enter parameter value" when i click on any of the checkboxes. Do you know how I can remove this prompt?

Comment: That's because your p2p view form is within another form "cases"? Check if you have link master/child fields set. Check if p2p view recordsource does not have a parameter

Comment: thanks. I set the master/child on the subform p2 view but when i set it for the p2p cases I lose my records, i only see 2 records, so i'm unsure how to set master/child for that subform. I think part of the problem is I have 2 subforms within 1 form (cases). And the reason it's set up this way is so that I can have a continuous form (p2p cases) above a single form (p2p view) in one form and ideally connect the 2 via view button. Are you saying I do not want a parameter on recordsource for p2p view? I appreciate your help- let me know if you're able to assist any further.

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to emulate a split form.

Comment: i got it working. thanks